Searching autodesk's data management API with a filter on a custom attribute
I'm very unfamiliar with Autodesk's data management API, but was asked to integrate some functionality in our own product, to show a selection of documents stored in Autodesk.
I am now using the Autodesk data management API to search for documents as described here, e.g. https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/:project_id/folders/:folder_id/search
This works fine for simple searches like filtering on filename, or date-modified, but I can't seem to search with a filter on custom attributes, which is a hard requirement. I'm not sure this is even possible.
The only alternative I have found so far is to simply retrieve all documents, and then use a batch-get request (in batches of 50 documents) to get custom attributes. I can then filter client side. Needless to say, this is very inefficient with thousands of documents.
I am now planning to cache search results in a database, and only search for documents that are modified since the previous search. Before doing that, I'd like to check if there is really no option to filter on a custom attributes.
